# What does the preventdefault() method when we put it in it our custom function in flex?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

What is functionality of `preventDefault()` in flex or flash builder ?

Answer (score 4):

this tells the event listeners that they shouldn't do "what they would normally do".

from the Adobe docs:

"some events have an associated default behavior. For example, the doubleClick event has an associated default behavior that highlights the word under the mouse pointer at the time of the event. Your event listener can cancel this behavior by calling the preventDefault() method. You can also make the current event listener the last one to process an event by calling the stopPropagation() or stopImmediatePropagation() method."

Answer (score 2):

preventDefault method of any event cancels the default behaviour of an event. As you can see as textfield can get input event and will showup a letter on every letter being typed. In this case it will cancel default behaviour and wont show up a letter being typed.